# counting number of duplicates - alternative to plyr package

Tags: r, ggplot2, duplicates, plyr

I am interested to count the number of duplicates in my data, so i can justify using kendall's tau for calculating the correlation coefficient between my variables. The following command does exactly what I want :

```
ddply(df,.(a,b ),nrow) # plyr package
```

However, the problem is with the `plyr` package. Once installed, my i get an error when running `ggplot` commands.

This is the list of package that I have installed in the session. I have tried restarting the session, no use.

```
packages(c("dplyr", "tidyr", "data.table", "ggplot2", "readxl", "magrittr", "tidyverse",
           "ggpubr", "forcats", "car", "PerformanceAnalytics", "mtcars", "Hmisc", "gplots",
           "nortest", "dunn.test", "psych", "FSA", "DescTools"))
```

I assume that the `plyr` package somehow interferes with my other packages.

**How can I solve this problem** ?

or

**Is there an alternative solution to  the `ddply` command?**

Comment: Maybe you could use length(data) - lenght(unique(data)). In case data is a df and not a vector nrows instead of length might work

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to count the number of duplicates using base R:

```
set.seed(111)
mydata <- sample(1:100, 100, 1)
(nDuplicates <- length(mydata) - length(unique(mydata)))

> (nDuplicates <- length(mydata) - length(unique(mydata)))
[1] 35
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have dplyr loaded, here's a dplyr method using mtcars as an example:

```
dups <- mtcars %>%
      group_by(cyl) %>%
      summarize(n()) %>%
      print
```